# How to check if a file can be opened by a third party application before download

Tags: android

In my application I want to download a file and view it.  The issue is that I need to check whether there is any third party application installed on the device that can open the file format(Mime) before it is downloaded.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` with the right MIME type and a fake path to the file (or, better yet, the path you intend to download it to). Then, use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` -- if you get back a list with 1+ items in it, then `startActivity()` on that `Intent` will succeed once you have downloaded the file.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare . Decreased 2 of my bugs

Comment: This piece of code is not working for videos in 3.0 and later.When i'm checking launchables for mimetype *video/3gp* , launcables count is 0.When i download and pass the URI using intent, it is being viewed by Videoplayer of the Device. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: @sha: Make sure you are using very similar `Intents`. For example, some video players can play local videos but not streaming ones. If you test using an `Intent` with an `http://` `Uri`, the local-only video player will not be a candidate, where an `Intent` with a `file://` `Uri` would succeed.

Comment: `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromFile(file));
main.setType("video/3gpp");
List<ResolveInfo> launchables = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.GET_INTENT_FILTERS);`

Comment: The above commented code is used by me.`queryIntentActivities` is returning a list of `ResolveInfo` whose size is 0.I hardcoded the **MimeType(video/3gpp)** Which is the tested media type playing in the device Media Player.I also tested by hardcoding MimeType with Video/* but couldnt suceeded in getting launchables.

Comment: @sha: Replace `PackageManager.GET_INTENT_FILTERS` with `0`.

Comment: still the same issue.Is there any other way to know the launchable third party applications?

Comment: Worked out.But with a small change i didn't understand.I set the data  for intent using `setDataandType` instead of passing data from constructor.Don't know whats the difference but worked out. :)